# .htaccess URL and directory redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

This is my first post so excuse me if something it's wrong with my way of asking for help. I've been reading other posts related to my problem but none solved it.

My path:

http://example.com/m/page1

http://example.com/m/page2

...
And so on.

I want to change the **/m/pageX** to **/m/#pageX** without hardcoding the URL and without using any additional php scripts.

At the first sight, I've accomplished this task by writing the following .htaccess configuration file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On    
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^[dm]/(.+)$ /m/#$1 [R=302,NE,L,NC]

## hide .php extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+common_([^.]+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L,NE]

## To internally forward
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/common_$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ common_$1.php [L]
```

1. Is my code the best solution or there is other way to approach my task ?
2. How can I redirect the /m/pageX to /d/#pageX ?

Thank you

Comment: The opposite: `the http://domain.com/d/about` needs to be redirected to `http://domain.com/m/#about`

Comment: Yes, I do have one but at the moment it's nothing there

Comment: At some point, when it tries to redirect me to `http://domain.com/#page` it puts two hashes. Do you have any improvements ? I'll put comments to tell you what I wantet to aquire

Comment: It's ok now ? I think that you wanted to replace the condition for all of that as I can see in your rule, right ?

Comment: That rule redirects me from site.com/m/pageX to site.com/m/# . At the same time will redirect me from site.com/d/pageX to site.com/m/#

Comment: Thank you very much. Still don't have the reputation to vote you up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these rules in your root .htaccess (a level above `/m/` and `/d/`):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^d/(.+)$ /m/#$1 [NE,NC,L,R=302]

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /#$1 [NE,L,R=302]
```

Make sure to **remove** any `/d/.htaccess` file.

If for some reason you want to do it from `/d/.htaccess` then use this rule in `/d/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /m/#$1 [NE,NC,L,R=302]
```

Comment: I am so stupid. I had one .htaccess in the /m folder also and that's the reason my method wasn't working. I'll update my first post with the final .htaccess file. You can suggest any improvements

Comment: what if I don't want to redirect someome which uses an iPhone from site.com/m to site.com/d but if he uses and iPad or desktop to redirect him from site.com/m to site.com/d ? Could this be added to this .htaccess ? Thanks

Comment: Please create a new question for that requirement as that will require major changes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27311877/htaccess-url-redirection-using-user-agent  I've done it. Really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

The # sign is not supported in URLs.

This will rewrite /m/pageX to /d/pageX:

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^m/(.*) /d/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This will rewrite /m/pageX to /d/pageX#example, but #example is fix:

```
RewriteEngine On   
RewriteRule ^m/(.*) /d/$1#example [NE,L,R=301]
```

[NE] is necessary to keep the hash (#) sign.

This will rewrite /m/pageX to /d/#pageX:

```
RewriteEngine On   
RewriteRule ^m/(.*) /d/#$1 [NE,L,R=301]
```

Comment: It doesn't work. To be more specific: when I access site.com/m/ I want the site to redirect me to site.com/d/ with the above rules.
So, site.com/m/example will become site.com/d/#example. Be aware of the '#' from the second link.

Comment: I added some more examples. Please forget about all your other rules. Are you aware of their meaning? I cannot even guess what you want to do with them. If you think that they are necessary, please write a comment for every line what you want to achieve with it.

Comment: In the first post I just wanted to make a rule so that a link: **example.com/m/page will** become **example.com/m/#page**. After doing this I just want to make what I wrote in the first comment(your posted steps). So, to be sure that this will go smoothly, will you please make it easy to put it all together? For now, I just put all of the rules that you added and I just need to cmplete the first part. Thank you

Comment: You cannot combine this rules as they are. Since your examples have the same base, how should mod_rewrite know with rule should be used?

We need to know the conditions.

Comment: Conditions: - 1) all of the links with this pattern: example.com/page should be redirected to example.com/#page - 2) if a user visits example.com/d he should be redirected to example.com/m with the above rules so that example.com/d/page will redirect him to example.com/m/#page (it should apply for all links with this pattern). Any hints please ?