# .htaccess hide pattern word and .php extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I've got more pages(in the same location) with the following names:

**site.com/common_page1.php**

**site.com/common_page2.php**

**site.com/common_page3.php**

...

And so on.

I want to redirect each page with that pattern to:

**site.com/page1**

**site.com/page2**

**site.com/page3**

So I have to hide the "**.php**" extension and "**common_**"

I have done the first part:

```
RewriteEngine On

## hide .php extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

## To internally forward
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

but I've got stuck with the "**common_**" rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

## hide .php extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+common_([^.]+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

## To internally forward
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/common_$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /common_$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Can you also please take a look at this thread [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27252048/htaccess-url-and-directory-redirect]?

Comment: Ok, I am waiting for your help @anubhava.