# .htaccess URL redirection using User Agent

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been trying to find a solution to my situation but none worked. I have the following htaccess file which does the following:

1. It redirects **site.com/m/page** to **site.com/m/#page**
2. I redirects **site.com/d/page** to **site.com/m/#page**
3. It deletes **.php** extension and the **common_** pattern which I had in front of the pages

The code so far:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On    
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^[dm]/(.+)$ /m/#$1 [R=302,NE,L,NC]

## hide .php extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+common_([^.]+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L,NE]

## To internally forward
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/common_$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ common_$1.php [L]
```

I would like the folowing:

a) If some user enters from an iPhone '**site.com/m/...**' , continue (do nothing)

b) If some user enters from a desktop ar iPad '**site.com/m/page**' to redirect him to '**site.com/d/#page**'

I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a new rule for this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !iphone [NC]
RewriteRule ^m/(.+)$ /d/#$1 [R=302,NE,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^[dm]/(.+)$ /m/#$1 [R=302,NE,L,NC]

## hide .php extension
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+common_([^.]+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L,NE]

## To internally forward
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/common_$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ common_$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thank you again anubhava. I've tested it and it looks perfect. I'll comment here again if there's any issue.

Comment: Would you still help me having this worked out ? It's drivin' me nuts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27412854/htaccess-rederect-url-to-specific-pattern

Comment: Sure I will check your new question.