# .htaccess redirect URL to specific pattern

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Supposing I have some URLs, looking like this:

- site.com/html/photographers-4.cfm?county=test1
- site.com/html/photographers-5.cfm?county=test2&speciality=test3
- site.com/html/photographers-9.cfm?address4=test4&county=test5
- site.com/html/photographers-10.cfm?county=test6&speciality=test7&address4=test8

where **testX** (...) may be the same or may differ.

How would I be able to rewrite each of these so that the URL will be more eye-catching ?

- site.com/test1-photographers
- site.com/test2-tes33-photographers
- site.com/test4-test5-photographers
- site.com/test7-test8-photographers

**county,speciality,address1,address2,address3,address4** are just examples. There could be more.

Supposing I have this particular link:

> photographers.co.uk/html/photographers-10.cfm?county=New
>   Hampshire&speciality=Wedding&address4=South Portsmouth

or

> photographers.co.uk/html/photographers-10.cfm?county=New
>   York&speciality=Wedding&address4=Portsmouth New City

I'd like the rule that when it finds a word like

> South Portsmouth

or

> Portsmouth New City

to follow my rules and to make it look like:

> South-Portsmouth

or

> Portsmouth New City

My .htaccess it's something like this:

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    # Turn mod_rewrite on
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*?)(?:\+|%20|\s)+(.+?)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2 [L,NE,R=302]
RewriteRule ^([_&/A-Za-z0-9\s]+)-([&/A-Za-z0-9\s]+)-([&/A-Za-z0-9\s]+)-Photographers?$ html/photographers-10.cfm?county=$1&speciality=$2&address4=$3&rwtn [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !rwtn
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^county=(.*)&speciality=(.*)&address4=(.*)
RewriteRule ^html/photographers-10\.cfm$ http://www.photographers.co.uk/%1-%2-%3-Photographers? [R=301,L]




RewriteRule ^([_&/A-Za-z0-9\s]+)-Photographers/?$ html/photographers-4.cfm?county=$1&rwtn [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !rwtn
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^county=(.*)
RewriteRule ^html/photographers-4\.cfm$ http://www.photographers.co.uk/%1-Photographers? [R=301,L]



RewriteRule ^([_&/A-Za-z0-9]+)-([&/A-Za-z0-9]+)-Photographers?$ html/photographers-5.cfm?county=$1&speciality=$2&rwtn [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !rwtn
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^county=(.*)&speciality=(.*)
RewriteRule ^html/photographers-5\.cfm$ http://www.photographers.co.uk/%1-%2-Photographers? [R=301,L]



RewriteRule ^Canary-Wharf-London-Photographer/?$ html/photographers-9.cfm?address4=Canary-Wharf&county=London&rwtn [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^City-of%2520London-London-Photographer/?$ html/photographers-9.cfm?address4=City-of%20London&county=London&rwtn [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^East-London-London-Photographer/?$ html/photographers-9.cfm?address4=East-London&county=London&rwtn [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Kingston-upon%2520Thames-London-Photographer/?$ html/photographers-9.cfm?address4=Kingston-upon Thames&county=London&rwtn [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^NOTTING-HILL-London-Photographer/?$ html/photographers-9.cfm?address4=NOTTING-HILL&county=London&rwtn [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^South-Woodford-London-Photographer/?$ html/photographers-9.cfm?address4=South-Woodford&county=London&rwtn [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Stamford-Brook-London-Photographer/?$ html/photographers-9.cfm?address4=Stamford-Brook&county=London&rwtn [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([_&/A-Za-z0-9\s]+)-([&/A-Za-z0-9\s]+)-Photographer/?$ html/photographers-9.cfm?address4=$1&county=$2&rwtn [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !rwtn
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^address4=(.*)&county=(.*)
RewriteRule ^html/photographers-9\.cfm$ http://www.photographers.co.uk/%1-%2-Photographer/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I have just edited the post to make my help more clear. Thanks

Comment: Well, it doesn't matter. I want to have this pattern whatever the city will be. It's that possible ?

Comment: If county=more than one word -> transform it to more-than-one-word and add it to the already existing rule. The same for address(If address=more than one word -> transform it to more-than-one-word and add it to the already existing rule). So the new url won't give me an error if county or address have words delimited by space.

Comment: How do I do this ? Do you have time to modify my code ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66792/discussion-between-alex-grajdeanu-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule as **your very first rule** to replace all your spaces by hyphen. Spaces can be in query string and/or in REQUEST_URI.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*?)(?:\+|%20|\s)+(.+?)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2 [L,NE,R=302]
```

This will redirect:

> `/html/photographers-10.cfm?county=New York&speciality=Wedding&address4=Portsmouth New City`

to:

> `/html/photographers-10.cfm?county=New-York&speciality=Wedding&address4=Portsmouth-New-City`

**Note all spaces have been converted to hyphen in final URI**

Comment: I've made what you said. Could you check if I put them where I should have ? Thank you

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. I am really trying to learn those rules by making different pages and situations. I'd have so much to ask, but at a certain point I will probably become annoying. Thank you again.

Comment: Apparently, I found an issue: I am getiing this page: http://www.photographers.co.uk/Nottinghamshire-Portrait-Nottingham-Photographers  instead of: http://www.photographers.co.uk/Nottingham-Portrait-Photographers

Can't figure it out where the problem might be. Any ideas ?

Comment: This is the original: http://www.photographers.co.uk/html/photographers-10.cfm?county=Nottinghamshire&speciality=Portrait&address4=Nottingham . It should become: http://www.photographers.co.uk/Nottingham-Portrait-Photographers . So taking Address4 and Speciality and adding Photographers as the last word

Comment: Yes, I know that. I just can't figure it out where is my mistake.

Comment: Done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607181/htaccess-rewriting-complex-url . Thanks for suggestion

Comment: Thanks, let me go through it.