# .htaccess rewriting complex URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following .htaccess containg some rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.*?)(?:\+|%20|\s)+(.+?)\sHTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2 [L,NE,R=302]
RewriteRule ^([_&/A-Za-z0-9\s]+)-([&/A-Za-z0-9\s]+)-([&/A-Za-z0-9\s]+)-Photographers?$ html/photographers-10.cfm?county=$1&speciality=$2&address4=$3&rwtn [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !rwtn
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^county=(.*)&speciality=(.*)&address4=(.*)
RewriteRule ^html/photographers-10\.cfm$ http://www.photographers.co.uk/%3-%2-Photographers? [R=301,L]




RewriteRule ^([_&/A-Za-z0-9\s]+)-Photographers/?$ html/photographers-4.cfm?county=$1&rwtn [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !rwtn
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^county=(.*)
RewriteRule ^html/photographers-4\.cfm$ http://www.photographers.co.uk/%1-Photographers? [R=301,L]



RewriteRule ^([_&/A-Za-z0-9]+)-([&/A-Za-z0-9]+)-Photographers?$ html/photographers-5.cfm?county=$1&speciality=$2&rwtn [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !rwtn
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^county=(.*)&speciality=(.*)
RewriteRule ^html/photographers-5\.cfm$ http://www.photographers.co.uk/%1-%2-Photographers? [R=301,L]



RewriteRule ^Canary-Wharf-London-Photographer/?$ html/photographers-9.cfm?address4=Canary-Wharf&county=London&rwtn [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^City-of%2520London-London-Photographer/?$ html/photographers-9.cfm?address4=City-of%20London&county=London&rwtn [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^East-London-London-Photographer/?$ html/photographers-9.cfm?address4=East-London&county=London&rwtn [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Kingston-upon%2520Thames-London-Photographer/?$ html/photographers-9.cfm?address4=Kingston-upon Thames&county=London&rwtn [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^NOTTING-HILL-London-Photographer/?$ html/photographers-9.cfm?address4=NOTTING-HILL&county=London&rwtn [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^South-Woodford-London-Photographer/?$ html/photographers-9.cfm?address4=South-Woodford&county=London&rwtn [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Stamford-Brook-London-Photographer/?$ html/photographers-9.cfm?address4=Stamford-Brook&county=London&rwtn [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^([_&/A-Za-z0-9\s]+)-([&/A-Za-z0-9\s]+)-Photographer/?$ html/photographers-9.cfm?address4=$1&county=$2&rwtn [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !rwtn
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^address4=(.*)&county=(.*)
RewriteRule ^html/photographers-9\.cfm$ http://www.photographers.co.uk/%1-%2-Photographer/? [R=301,L]
```

When I click this link on my website:

http://www.photographers.co.uk/html/photographers-10.cfm?county=Nottinghamshire&speciality=Portrait&address4=Nottingham

It **should** redirect me to:

http://www.photographers.co.uk/Nottingham-Portrait-Photographers

But **it is actually redirecting** me to:

http://www.photographers.co.uk/Nottinghamshire-Portrait-Nottingham-Photographers

Any help,please ?

Comment: It's doing what it's told in the very first rewrite rule set (at the end) where it's rewriting `%{QUERY_STRING} ^county=(.*)&speciality=(.*)&address4=(.*)` into `http://www.photographers.co.uk/%1-%2-%3-Photographers?` where the country is `%1` the speciality is `%2` and address4 is `%3`. You can simply change that line to `http://www.photographers.co.uk/%3-%2-Photographers?` if you want. Just remember all addresses like this will translate into that form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
RewriteRule ^html/photographers-10\.cfm$ http://www.photographers.co.uk/%1-%2-%3-Photographers? [R=301,L]
```

should be:

```
RewriteRule ^html/photographers-10\.cfm$ http://www.photographers.co.uk/%3-%2-Photographers? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Could you also take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27453951/how-to-redirect-pattern-url-to-a-specific-page-but-keep-the-same-url ?